# Need to change class of dividing <li> on selecting <li>

Tags: jquery, css

I have managed to get the navigation to change it's class if it has been selected but the part I can not work out is how to select and change the class of the  dividing pipe character between each navigation item as well.

You can see it here  http://prosper.businesscatalyst.com/news.html  I want to be able to change the colour of the pipe's background to match the pipe character making for a solid block of the one colour.

Here's the code and html I am using to select and change the menu item, but it's as far as I can get. I want to change the class="pipeBuffer" to class="pipeBufferSelect" if I can when the menu item is selected.

Any help greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
    <ul id="subnavlist">
        <li class="pipeBuffer">|</li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="pipeBuffer">|</li>
        <li><a href="finance-homeloans.html"> Finance </a> </li>
        <li class="pipeBuffer">|</li>
        <li><a href="life-insurance-private.html"> Life Insurance</a></li>
        <li class="pipeBuffer">|</li>
        <li><a href="general-insurance-private.html"> General Insurance</a></li>
        <li class="pipeBuffer">|</li>
        <li><a href="advisors.html"> Advisors</a> </li>
        <li class="pipeBuffer">|</li>
        <li><a href="news.html"> News</a> </li>
        <li class="pipeBuffer">|</li>
        <li><a href="#"> Resources</a> </li>
        <li class="pipeBuffer">|</li>
        <li><a href="#"> Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //this is highlighting a selected menu item
        $('#subnavlist li a  ').each(function(index) {
            if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            $(this).parent().parent().siblings(':first').addClass("selected");
        });       

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does this work?    
$(this).closest(li).siblings(':first').addClass("selected");

Comment: do you mean `$(this).parent().next("li")` & `$(this).parent().prev("li")`

Comment: Do you want `$(this).closest('li').prev('li').addClass("pipeBufferSelect").removeClass("pipeBuffer");`?

Comment: This nearly works, except it adds the class to all of the pipeBuffer classes - thanks.

Comment: vasa - no it didn't, but thanks for your attention anyway - appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Use click event in jquery to click the menu item .

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#subnavlist li a').click(function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            $('#subnavlist li a').removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected");

            $('#subnavlist li').removeClass("pipeBufferSelect").addClass("pipeBuffer");
            $(this).closest("li").removeClass("pipeBuffer").addClass("pipeBufferSelect");

        });       

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#subnavlist li a').click(function(){
       var checkClass = $(this).parent().next().attr('class').split(' ');
         alert(checkClass[1]);

         if(checkClass[1] == "pipeBufferSelect"){
             $(this).parent().next().removeClass('pipeBufferSelect');                                       
         }else
         {

        $(this).parent().next().addClass('pipeBufferSelect');
         }


    });
    //this is highlighting a selected menu item
    $('#subnavlist li a ').each(function(index) {
        if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(this).parent().parent().siblings(':first').addClass("selected");
    });       


});
```

Try this code it will add the class "pipeBufferSelect" on click of the li.